# The "WireUpCoreRuntime" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I use Visual Studio 2015 RTM with windows 10 RTM, created an Universal App. The debug passed but when I try to run with "local machine" option , first VS return error "copyWin32Resources failed with exit code 500" (some time with code 701 ...), then the second time it return "The "WireUpCoreRuntime" task failed unexpectedly"

I've try re-install VS but it's not work, and re-create a new project is not a good solution , i thought.

I've try searching google for this error , and surprisingly - no result returned.

[image]

[image: Update error's detail]

Comment: I did find some similar issue in MS internal DB, but seems not exact what you encountered. I will suggest you to get more information by enabling diagnostics build log. Tools-Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run ->change MSBuild output to diagnostics. And it's really worth to try create a new project to narrow down if this issue only occurs in this project or all project.

Comment: @AlanYao yes, create a new project and this issue still exist, and I've also updated issue's detail here.

Comment: Seems the file is locked by something. Maybe the Visual Studio itself, but doesn't happen on my side. I've heard this kind of issue caused by extension or third-party software. Open Developer command prompt for VS2015-> run devenv -safemode ->Clean the solution and try to rebuild it.

Comment: @AlanYao finally I found the reason, it's because of my antivirus which (I have no idea how and why) prevent VS from building / debugging.

Comment: Out of despair I tried to use Blend 2015 - I can compile and run the sample I am having.

Answer (score 0):

For those who also have this issue: disable antivirus will fix this problem since it prevent visual studio from copy some resources need for building /debugging here (I don't now how and why)

In my case , I use Panda Antivirus.

Comment: Good finding. But I don't think disable the antivirus is a good solution. it's better to consult the third-party vendor to ask if there is any rule that can be set to stop locking files but still can protect your PC.